# Vector difference while preserving order

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, set-difference

I have two `char` vectors say `{'G', 'K', 'A', 'L', 'P'}` and `{'K', 'P', 'T', 'M'}`. I have to get the difference between these two vectors while preserving the order i.e. `{'G', 'A', 'L'}`.

I am aware of `std::set_difference` function but that can't be used since that will require the vectors to be sorted. Is there any optimized way to do this in C++?

Comment: What would be the result of `{A, B, C, A, B, C}` and `{B, A}` ?

Comment: I don't have repeated elements in either list and order should be retained as in the first list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a `std::set` only from the second vector to get logarithmic lookup complexity, then iterate through the first vector, pushing to the resulting vector if the element is **not found** in the set:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> a = {'G', 'K', 'A', 'L', 'P'};
    std::vector<char> b = {'K', 'P', 'T', 'M'};
    std::vector<char> result;

    std::set<char> s(b.begin(), b.end());

    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
                 [&s](char elem) { return s.find(elem) == s.end(); });

    for(auto elem : result)
        std::cout << elem << ", ";

    return 0;
}
```

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03d59ca1d3682a90)

If you want to **subtract only the number of values found in the second vector**, remake this with `std::multiset`, where you also `erase` the element in the set if found:

```
std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [&s](char elem)
{
    auto it = s.find(elem);

    if(it == s.end())
        return true;

    s.erase(it);
    return false;
});
```

Note that the above will remove first occurrences and keep later ones.

```
std::copy_if(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), ...
```

will do the opposite, but it will also give you reversed output.

Answer (score 0):

Manual solution:

```
std::vector<char> a{'G','K','A','L','P'};
std::vector<char> b{'K','P','T','M'};
std::vector<char> result;

for(auto const& item:a){
   if(std::find(std::begin(b),end(b),item)==std::end(b)){
       result.push_back(item)
   }
}
```

Comment: This is O(n^2).  I think that is the least optimized way to do this.

Comment: Yup.. it is just a clear (may not be clean) way to do it. I know this will not be accepted at all. but I think it should be mentioned for any beginner coming to this question later.