# C++ `std::set_difference` with different output for different compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

Now, I have code below which just tests the `std::set_difference` in the standard library:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
    public:
        Node(int x) : foo(x){}
    int foo = 10;
};

using NodePtrVec = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>;
using NodePtr = std::shared_ptr<Node>;
using IntVec = std::vector<int>;
int main(void){

    // pointer test
    NodePtr inA_1 = std::make_shared<Node>(1);
    NodePtr inA_2 = std::make_shared<Node>(11);
    NodePtr inA_3 = std::make_shared<Node>(111);

    NodePtr inB_1 = std::make_shared<Node>(2);
    NodePtr inB_2 = std::make_shared<Node>(22);
    NodePtr inB_3 = std::make_shared<Node>(222);

    NodePtr both_1 = std::make_shared<Node>(3);
    NodePtr both_2 = std::make_shared<Node>(33);


    NodePtrVec a{inA_1,inA_2,inA_3,both_1,both_2};
    NodePtrVec b{inB_1,inB_2,inB_3,both_1,both_2};
    NodePtrVec c{};
    std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(c));

    for(const auto& tmp : c){
        std::cout << tmp->foo << std::endl;
    }
    // int test
    std::cout << "int test" << std::endl;
    IntVec int_a = {1,5,4,2,3};
    IntVec int_b = {1,10,7};
    IntVec int_c;
    std::set_difference(int_a.begin(), int_a.end(), int_b.begin(), int_b.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(int_c));

    for(const auto& tmp : int_c){
        std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I compile this with Clang/GCC, I got outputs:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
1
11
111
int test
5
4
2
3
```

**UPDATE**
the source code case I want to actually use (suppose `Node` are some actions I will do. So these actions will happen in the order of `total`):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
    public:
        Node(int x) : foo(x){}
    int foo = 10;
};

using NodePtrVec = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>;
using NodePtr = std::shared_ptr<Node>;
using IntVec = std::vector<int>;
int main(void){

    // pointer test
    NodePtr inA_1 = std::make_shared<Node>(1);
    NodePtr inA_2 = std::make_shared<Node>(11);
    NodePtr inA_3 = std::make_shared<Node>(111);

    // total elements
    NodePtrVec total{inA_1,inA_2,inA_3};
    // sub set of the elements
    NodePtrVec sub{inA_2};
    NodePtrVec c{};
    // just want to get the compliment of the sub in total
    // as expected, c should be {inA_1,inA_3}
    std::set_difference(total.begin(), total.end(), sub.begin(), sub.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(c));

    for(const auto& tmp : c){
        std::cout << tmp->foo << std::endl;
    }
}
```

OK, this seems good and it actually correspond to the [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)., check the link:https://godbolt.org/z/MnvbKE97e
But when I choose MSVC, I got different outputs (check the link: https://godbolt.org/z/nYre1Eono):

```
example.cpp
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
example.cpp
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
1
11
111
3
33
int test
5
4
2
3
```

oops, we got unexpected results! By the way, It seems outputs will change when I changed the MSVC compiler version. But Why?

Comment: You are comparing addresses of the pointers in `std::set_difference`, not the value those pointer point to.  Whatever behavior you get is going to "correct".  You need to pass a custom comparator to `std::set_difference` to dereference the pointers and compare what they point to.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know what you mean, thanks.  But if I just want to find the different pointers  between two vectors, I still need to compare the dereferenced objects?

Comment: @NathanOliver At this situation, I actually just want to compare addresses to find out different nodes in two vectors.

Comment: @NathanOliver I can ensure that all the pointers are from just one source. These two vectors' elements are just from the source. So i think I don't need to compare the value. Back to the question, it actually produce different outputs.

Comment: Please make sure that your question is accurate.  It is not good practice at Stack Overflow to change your question to invalidate the correct answers you have already gotten.

Comment: Duplicate?  [Vector difference while preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363183/vector-difference-while-preserving-order)

Answer (score 4):

The ranges input to `set_difference` have to be sorted. Yours are not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, in your case `std::set_difference` is comparing `shared_ptr`, not the values your pointers are pointing to. It could still work of course, because `std::shared_ptr` has `operator==` that just compares the addresses of raw pointers, however the requirement of [set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) is that your ranges are sorted, which is not the case if you look at the output of MSVC (looks like clang by chance allocated memory in ascending order, which resulted in sorted vectors). Sort your vectors first:

```
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
```

and you will get your [desired output](https://godbolt.org/z/v4nv3hrTh) also with MSVC. Or even better, sort your vectors using custom comparator, and then calculate the set difference using custom comparator, which will be more idiomatic:

```
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return lhs->foo < rhs->foo; });
std::sort(b.begin(), b.end(), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return lhs->foo < rhs->foo; });
std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(c), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
    return lhs->foo < rhs->foo;
});
```

EDIT

I just read in the comments that you actually want to compare the pointers, not the values they point to. In this case, first part of my answer is the most relevant.

EDIT2:

> So these actions will happen in the order of total

Then you either have to copy your vector, sort it, and calculate the difference, or you cannot use `std::set_difference` in your situation. If the relative order of your actions needs to be preserved, maybe try this: iterate over A and insert the element to C if it does not exist in B. Since only order of elements in A needs to be preserved, use `std::unordered_set` for your container B, because it has constant-time lookup (on average):

```
NodePtrVec total{inA_1,inA_2,inA_3};
std::unordered_set<NodePtr> sub{inA_2};
NodePtrVec c{};
for (auto el : total)
{
    if (sub.count(el) == 0)
    {
        c.push_back(el);
    }
}
```